# Simple proof of the following: A matrix $A$ is onto if and only if its rows are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Saw this claim in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBSf2pGYAcA&list=PL06960BA52D0DB32B&index=4 at 23m35s and struggled in vain to prove it.

Searching for it on Google proved fruitless.

Comment: What do you mean by "matrix $A$ is onto"?

Comment: $$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}^m, \exists x \ \ \ \textrm{such that} \ \ \ y = Ax$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple proof. Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces. Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map. Let $A$ be any matrix representing this map. Then $\newcommand\rk{\operatorname{rank}}\rk A$ is the dimension of the image of $T$, and the number of rows of $A$ is the dimension of $W$. Thus for $T$ to be surjective, we must have that the rank of $A$ is equal to the number of rows of $A$. Since row rank equals column rank, the rank of $A$ is the number of linearly independent rows of $A$. Hence $T$ is surjective if and only if the rows of any matrix representing it are linearly independent.

**Edit** I realized there a perhaps slightly more direct proof, which sort of mixes the proof above with the proof that row rank equals column rank.

**Review of some relevant linear algebra**

First recall some notions. If $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$, then the dual vector space to $V$ is defined to be $V^*:=\newcommand\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom_K(V,K)$. If $T:V\to W$ is a linear map, then its dual is $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ defined by $T^*(\lambda) = \lambda \circ T$. Also if $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are bases for $V$ and $W$ with dual bases $\{v_i^*\}$ and $\{w_j^*\}$, then it is easy to show that the matrix for $T$ with respect to the $v_i$ and $w_j$s is $A_{ij}=w_j^*Tv_i$, and the matrix for $T^*$ with respect to $w_j^*$ and $v_i^*$ is $B_{ji}=(T^*w_j^*)v_i=(w_j^*\circ T)v_i=w_j^*Tv_i=A_{ij}$. Thus the matrix for $T^*$ is the transpose of the matrix for $T$.

Now onto the proof

**Proof**

Let $T:V\to W$. Let $A$ be any matrix representing this map. Then $T$ is surjective if and only if there are no nonzero linear functionals on $W$ that vanish on the image of $T$. However if $\lambda$ vanishes on the image of $T$, then we have $T^*\lambda=0$, and recalling that the matrix of $T^*$ is $A^t$, we see that the coordinates of $\lambda$ give an explicit linear dependence among the columns of $A^t$ (which are the rows of $A$). Conversely any linear dependence among the rows of $A$ gives such  a linear functional $\lambda$, proving that $T$ is not surjective.

Comment: I think that works. It might also be worth noting that for an m x n matrix to be surjective, we must have that m <= n (i.e. it must be a fat matrix). Hence, the rank of the matrix is at most min(m, n) = m. And if the rows are linearly dependent, then we have that the rank is strictly less than m.

Comment: @JamesShapiro That's also a reasonable direction of proof.

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix A to be onto, there has to be a pivot in every row. To test the linear independence of the rows, you can look at A$^T$ and row reduce. If every column of A$^T$ has a pivot, the columns are linearly independent. Note that the columns of A$^T$ are the rows of A. I leave it to you to show that the row reduction doesn't affect the linear independence.

Comment: Okay, I follow that argument and was aware of it before I asked the question. But that's not exactly a satisfying formal proof, in my opinion.